# Creating eclipse EMF from Schema

Tags: apache-spark, xsd, pyspark, emf, eclipse-emf

I am currently parsing large volume of data using Spark. Spark infers the schema after reading all the data. I would like to use this schema to generate Eclipse EMF. But the schema that gets generated in Spark is not in standard XSD format. It is in Json format and I couldn't come up with generic way of converting this Json to XSD. Do you know if I can create XSD when Spark infers the schema?

Comment: Not aware of how to manipulate Spark to achive your results, but for EMF you could easily create a script that reads in your JSON and creates a valid corresponding ecore model. You could either create the XML of the ecore model as a text file using any scripting language (I prefer [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) ) or you could generate compatible JSON that can be interpreted by the emf-json binding [emfjson](http://emfjson.org). So you could create a little JS file to read your specific Spark-JSON and transform it to some compatible Ecore JSON.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here.

https://epub.jku.at/obvulioa/content/pageview/6390647?query=berardinelli

A JSON schema (conforming to JSON Schema Draft 7) can be converted to an Ecore metamodel and Xtext grammar. Please check the linked GitHub and Zenodo repositories for further information.